# Finding optimum lower key combinations needed to find higher key combinations

Tags: algorithm, collections, combinations

UPDATE: For below problem,Got pointers on how to do it with Longest Common Subsequence method.

I've run into a case wherein given a Map of collections, with entries as below;

```
<A1, List1>
<A2, List2>
<B1, List3>
<B2, List4>
<C1, List5>
<C2, List6>
<D1, List7>
<D2, List8>
```

A) At fixed intervals, all collections within the map gets updated.

B) Each time an update happens, I would need to find intersection of elements, within the collection based on combination of map key.  Going with above example map;

at each update would have to find intersection of elements for 2 key combinations

```
    (2 key combinations)
    ————————————————————
    (A1-B1)
    (A1-B2)

    (A1-C1)
    (A1-C2)

    (A1-D1)
    (A1-D2)

    (B1-C1)
    (B1-C2)

    (B2-C1)
    (B2-C2)

    (B2-D1)
    (B2-D2)

    (C1-D1)
    (C1-D2)

    (C2-D1)
    (C2-D2)
```

Followed by;

C) finding intersection for 3 key combinations

```
    (3 key combinations)
    ————————————————————
    (A1-B1-C1)
    (A1-B1-C2)
```

Now to find the 3 key combination A1-B1-C1, it could be done by combining elements from the 2 key combinations of

```
    (A1-B1) && (B1-C1)     OR       (A1-C1) && (B1-C1)
```

So if I were to use (A1-B1) && (B1-C1), there is no need to find combination of (A1-C1) at all, since its redundant.

D) Like explained in C, how do I find out the optimum lower key combinations needed to find higher key combinations ? 
            In actual scenario, I’m working with over 200 keys to get possible combinations. Please note that the higher key combinations are only a select few hundred and not all possible combinations.

(Adding additional clarification to Joseph's comment)

E) The reason I would need to find (n-1) key tuple combination is because it could be used in computation of other (n) key tuples.

Going with the above example:

Consider that I would want to compute the 3-key combinations of

```
    (A1-C1-D1) AND (A1-C1-D2).
```

Now it becomes logical NOT to compute 2-key combination of (A1-B1) but compute (A1-C1) instead. Because of the fact that, results of (A1-C1) could be used in turn to compute 3, 3-key combinations of (A1-B1-C1), (A1-C1-D1) & (A1-C1-D2). While in the case of (A1-B1), it could only be used to compute 1 3-key combination of (A1-B1-C1)

F) Thus, I would like a way to find out the most optimal (n-1) key tuples which could be used for computing n-key tuple combinations.

---

UPDATE: Got pointers on how to do it with Longest Common Subsequence.

Comment: If the goal is finding all `n-tuples` then I think you would be better off generating all `n-tuples` by looking at your original list instead of creating it from the `(n-1)-tuple` list. Or are you concerned with the identifying the specific `(n-1)-tuples` that make up each `n-tuple`?

Comment: Hello Joseph, Its the latter. The reason I would need to find (n-1) key tuple combination is because it could be used in computation of other (n) key tuples.

 Going with the above example:

  Consider that I would want to compute the 3-key combinations of (A1-C1-D1) & (A1-C1-D2). Now it becomes logical NOT to compute 2-key combination of (A1-B1) but compute (A1-C1) instead. Because of the fact that it could be used to compute 3, 3-key combinations of (A1-B1-C1), (A1-C1-D1) & (A1-C1-D2).

Thanks,
 Anish